# images blurry in stock browser

Tags: images, stock-browser, zooming

How do I disable the automatic zoom-in in stock browser? It makes the images very blurry and eye strain. What I want is small but sharp (which is what opera does)

Answer (score 0):

in `ICS 4.0.4`: Open stock browser, click **Menu**, click **Settings**, from the list, got to **Advanced** section, about middle of page, click on **Default Zoom** and select **Medium**.

in other versions, if available, it is somewhere near that!

Comment: -1 It is already set as that.